# Download File from link in Outlook Task Pane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

I am building an office-js addin for Outlook and have hit a hard snag.  On a ReadMessage TaskPane I massage some data and end up with a Base64 representation of a binary file. I can create a Blob or data: href for it and I create a link.
In Outlook for the web, I am able to get it to download the file without a problem.

However, I have not been able to figure out a way to download it from Outlook for Windows/Mac Desktop.

Tried using download.js and Filesaver.js. Blob URLs, etc. I cant seem to get the file to be downloaded from the Windows or Mac desktop.

How can this be accomplished?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a blob is not support on Mac and Windows. Something you can do is call the OpenBrowser window API in Windows. And provide a download link from that window. This call is coming to Mac, but is not available yet. Full documentation for this function will be provided soon. It is currently available on Win32 Outlook C2R versions (i.e. the subscription), and Win32 Outlook 2019. (Mac api is coming soon) It is not available on OWA.

Sample syntax:

Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("https://www.msn.com");

Comment: Is there an expected ETA on openBrowserWindow method being supported in mac and windows? Which version was it introduced? Preview or 1.8?  The only place I found anything pertaining to this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: Sorry, we don't have an ETA to share at this point for its support on Mac. It will be introduced as part of a new API set, and not a part of Preview or 1.8. Full documentation will be provided soon.